# Plotting Shapefile and Raster on the same ggplot plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, geospatial, raster, shapefile

I'm having an issue plotting raster bathymetry data and a shapefile on the same plot. I think it is a projecting issue but I'm not sure.

When I run the code I get this as an error: Coordinate system already present. Adding new coordinate system, which will replace the existing one.
Error: geom_sf() must be used with coord_sf()

```
############################################################################################ 
############################
# ATLANTIC COAST RIVER HERRING MIGRATION VIZ
# script to plot States, Topography, Catch 
# author:

############################################################################################

library(ncdf4) 
library(raster) 
library(rgdal) 
library(ggplot2)
library(fields)
library(reshape)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(maps)
library(rgdal)
library(gridExtra)
library(maptools)
library(scales)
library(raster)
library(rgeos)
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
library(mapplots)
library(dplyr)    
library(mapproj)
library(ggmap)
library(ggspatial)
library(sf)
library(ggrepel)
library(cowplot)
library(rnaturalearth)
library(rnaturalearthdata)
library(rnaturalearthhires)
library(stringr)
library(marmap)
library(oce)
library(terra)
library(rasterVis)

theme(
  text = element_text(family = "Ubuntu Regular", color = "#22211d"),
  axis.line = element_blank(),
  axis.text.x = element_blank(),
  axis.text.y = element_blank(),
  axis.ticks = element_blank(),
  axis.title.x = element_blank(),
  axis.title.y = element_blank(),
  # panel.grid.minor = element_line(color = "#ebebe5", size = 0.2),
  panel.grid.major = element_line(color = "#ebebe5", size = 0.2),
  panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
  plot.background = element_rect(fill = "#f5f5f2", color = NA), 
  panel.background = element_rect(fill = "#f5f5f2", color = NA), 
  legend.background = element_rect(fill = "#f5f5f2", color = NA),
  panel.border = element_blank())

wd <- "D:/R/DataViz" # top level working directory
setwd(wd)

##############################################################################################

# STATE BORDERS
# read in shape border shapefile
# data from https://github.com/jasperdebie/VisInfo/blob/master/us-state-capitals.csv
state_borders <- readOGR(paste(wd, "/shapefiles/stateBorders/statesp010g.shp", sep=""))
state_borders <- spTransform(state_borders, CRS("+proj=utm +zone=18 +datum=NAD83 +units=m+no_defs"))
# below code fixes some bad polygons in this shapefile
# simplify the polgons a tad (tweak 0.00001 to your liking)
state_borders <- gSimplify(state_borders, tol = 0.00001)
# this is a well known R / GEOS hack (usually combined with the above) to 
# deal with "bad" polygons
state_borders <- gBuffer(state_borders, byid=TRUE, width=0)
# any bad polys?
sum(gIsValid(state_borders, byid=TRUE)==FALSE)

##############################################################################################

#Albemarle Sound Bathy
# READ IN AND PARSE BATHYMETRY DATA
# from https://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/thredds/catalog/regional/catalog.html?dataset=regionalDatasetScan/albemarle_sound_s010_30m.nc

ABSound <- raster('albemarle_sound_s010_30m.nc')
ABSound <- as.data.frame(ABSound, xy = TRUE)
extents <- extent(ABSound)

#############################################################################################

###Set up for plotting

ymax <- 4051522
extents@ymax <- ymax
ymin <- 3945472
extents@ymin <- ymin
xmax <- 445624.1
extents@xmax <-  xmax
xmin <- 325264.1
extents@xmin <- xmin

state_borders_sf <- st_as_sf(state_borders)
state_borders_sf_crop <- st_crop(state_borders_sf, xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax,
                             ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax)



ggplot() +
  geom_raster(aes(x=x, y=y, fill = GDAL.Band.Number.1), data = ABSound) +
  ylab("") +
  xlab("") +
  geom_sf(data=state_borders_sf_crop, fill="black", color=NA) +
  geom_sf(data=state_borders_sf, size=0.2, fill=NA, color=alpha("white",0.2) ) +
  coord_sf(expand = FALSE, xlim=c(xmin, xmax), ylim=c(ymin, ymax)) +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_line(color = gray(.5), linetype = "dashed", size = 0.7),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = "black"),
        plot.title = element_text(color = "black", size = 16, hjust = 0.5),
        legend.position = "none") +
  coord_equal()
```

Comment: What happens when you remove `coord_equal()` from the last line? I'm not too keen on loading all of those packages plus downloading the shapefile to reproduce this (though I don't think you use all of those packages here anyway)

Comment: That worked, can you explain why to help me in the future?

Comment: Could you try to trim to code to the bare minimum to reproduce the issue? For example, I highly doubt that the plot theming is relevant for the problem, nor is it likely that all packages you list are needed to trigger the problem (as Allan also indicates).

Answer (score 0):

As posted in the comments, the solution was to simply remove coord_equal() at the end of the ggplot code.

Comment: `sf` objects will only be plotted in `ggplot` when the `coord` is set to `coord_sf` - this is done automatically when you call `geom_sf`. If you add a different coord, after this, `ggplot` doesn't know how you intend to represent the `sf` object and just bails out.